# How to use Html.ActionLink 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page which contains the following code:

```
Html.ActionLink("Hi", "Hi", new { controller = "Home", action = "TD", id = "123" })
```

I am now moving this code to a webservice (.asmx) and the above code doesn't work.

I've tried using:

`System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink`

But this needs a parameter `this HtmlHelper htmlHelper`. I've tried passing null but that doesn't work.

Can you please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: why dont you use the HTML link directly and pass the needed url to the href attribute? <a href='site.com.asmx?id=123'>text</a>

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Html.ActionLink("HeadingYouWantToProvide", "ViewYouWantToShow", "YourControllerYouwant", null, new {id="IdyouwanttoPass"}
```

So

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hi","TD","Home",null, new {id="123"})
```